# How to get a WPF rich textbox into a string

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I saw how to set a [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) rich text box in *[RichTextBox Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx)*.

Yet I like to save its text to the database like I used to, in [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms).

```
string myData = richTextBox.Text;
dbSave(myData);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why use a RichTextBox, if you only want the text? Wouldnt it be better to just use a TextBox instead? :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

At the bottom of the MSDN [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) reference there's a link to [How to Extract the Text Content from a RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754041.aspx)

It's going to look like this:

```
public string RichTextBoxExample()
{
    RichTextBox myRichTextBox = new RichTextBox();

    // Create a FlowDocument to contain content for the RichTextBox.
    FlowDocument myFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();

    // Add initial content to the RichTextBox.
    myRichTextBox.Document = myFlowDoc;

    // Let's pretend the RichTextBox gets content magically ... 

    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
        // TextPointer to the start of content in the RichTextBox.
        myRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, 
        // TextPointer to the end of content in the RichTextBox.
        myRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd
    );

    // The Text property on a TextRange object returns a string
    // representing the plain text content of the TextRange.
    return textRange.Text;
}
```

Comment: +1 :this is a bit complicated for something so basic. It's useful to control start and finish yet in most of the time not needed and I still expect .text or .context etc.

Comment: @Asaf I don't think this is that complicated, the RichTextBox is not a plain text document. There is formatting, styles, etc associated with a RichTextBox, and so it makes sense to have an Object based backing.

Comment: you may be right but I'm loosing my hair here quiet fast: basics like set text, clearText (=""), or putting the string value in a function are avoiding me.It may make sense but it's not friendly at all.