# How to get all text from RichTextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, .net-4.5

I need to get exactly all text from a WPF RichTextBox.

Everyone ([How to get a WPF rich textbox into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125310/how-to-get-a-wpf-rich-textbox-into-a-string), [RichTextBox (WPF) does not have string property "Text"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754041(v=vs.110).aspx and many more) agrees a code like this one:

```
public static string GetText(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
    string text = textRange.Text;
    return text;
}
```

but it add a trailling "\r\n". In a very simple case:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="mRichTextBox">
  <FlowDocument>
    <Section>
      <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="The dog is brown. The cat is black."/>
      </Paragraph>
    </Section>
  </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

I get:

> "The dog is brown. The cat is black.\r\n"

It can be seen as a minor issue but really I need exact text.

- Do you know why?
- Is it safe to simply ignore one trailing "\r\n"?
- Is my code correct?
- Is there any other gotcha (I mean differences between real text and what I get from my GetText)?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need your RichTextBox to be multiline? You could disable it and shouldn't have the problem.

Comment: You don't think that a Paragraph should end with a new line?  You are getting the real text.

Comment: return text.TrimEnd()

Comment: @justsomeguy This is what I'm doing now but I am not satisfied. I can understand NewLine as a separator between Paragraph but not as the end of last paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the multiline you can disable it and shouldn't have this problem.

You could also remove them  like this:

```
  string text = textRange.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

Also if you only want to remove the last ocurrence you can use a function like this:

```
public static string ReplaceLastOccurrence(string Source, string Find, string Replace)
{
    int Place = Source.LastIndexOf(Find);
    string result = Source.Remove(Place, Find.Length).Insert(Place, Replace);
    return result;
}
```

And use it like this.

```
 string text = ReplaceLastOccurrence(textRange.Text,Environment.NewLine,"");
```

**Every time you have a  you will get a New Line at the end, so make sure you handle it acordingly.**

Comment: I need multiline edit ("The dog is brown. The cat is black." is only a sample) and I need exact text. I resolved to remove a possible "\r\n" at the end of my string but I need to know why it appends and if there is other differences.

Comment: You have <Paragraph> and my guess is that each time you do you have a new line if not empty.

Comment: And you should use the method with the Environment.NewLine and not with \r\n, its cleaner and portable.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right about one <Paragraph>, one NewLine rule. Do you know if there is other differences between entered text and GetText?

Comment: No, im not sure if you could enter the text without paragraph to avoid this, anyway if you remove the Environment.NewLine for each Paragraph it should be OK.

Comment: I was searching a way to have same contents after roundtrip of SetText(GetText()). I will then add `if (text.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
 text = text.Remove(text.Length - Environment.NewLine.Length);`
to my GetText hoping no other differences exists. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

But you are getting the actual text.
You don't think a parargraph should end with a new line?

Try this and copy paste from the screen to notepad

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="mRichTextBox">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Section>
            <Paragraph/>
            <Paragraph/>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="The dog is brown. The cat is black."/>
            </Paragraph>
        </Section>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: I have seen that each empty Paragraph is exported as a newline but I don't understand why the last non empty Paragraph is generating a trailing NewLine. In each text editor (notepad, Word, Visual Studio and any other), you have a difference between ending a text with or without a new line. If a newline is forced, I can remove it but I need to know if it will be the only difference.

Comment: And you have seen that a non empty Paragraph end with a new line.  Are you starting to see a pattern here?

Comment: I need to be able to have exactly same content after Setting text gathered by a GetText. I use following SetText:
`public static void SetText(RichTextBox rtb, string text)
{
 TextRange textRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
 textRange.Text = text;
}`
If I don't remove one trailing "\r\n", I have a new empty Paragraph after each SetText(GetText()) wich is troublesome.
But I also need to know if there is other differences between entered text and what I get.