# How to cast System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.Text as String?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox

I have this `RichTextBox rtEvents` from click-drag in form designer and I want to cast the `rtEvents` value into string.

[This solution doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125310/how-to-get-a-wpf-rich-textbox-into-a-string), because I am not using `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox`

I don't want to use `.Windows.Controls.*` because its difficult for  me to design the form without click-drag.

Is there any other way or workaround for it?

Comment: have you tried `string textContent= rtEvents.Text`

Comment: Yes, it doenst work :(

Comment: If this is WPF, you are already using  `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox` and the final part of your link should work (The part where a TextRange is extracted and then used for the Text property)

Comment: What "*doesn't work*"? What have you tried so far? What does happen?

Comment: @Sayse that "doesn't work" have a link

Comment: @un-lucky it works, after I added using System.Windows.Controls; .... :o

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, somehow I solved it (not sure if this is the good/perfect way),

By adding `using System.Windows.Controls;` but I have to add this extra `System.Windows.Forms.` for all of my objects. For example I have this function:

```
private void dDownWidth(Combobox cbname)
{
.....
}
```

Before I add : `using System.Windows.Controls;` it works like that, but after I add, it have to be like this:

```
private void dDownWidth(System.WIndows.Forms.Combobox cbname)
{
.....
}
```

I have to changes it like that for all the objects/parameters objects.

Answer (score 0):

string richText = new TextRange(rtEvents .Document.ContentStart, rtEvents .Document.ContentEnd).Text;